# trigger to stop adding duplicate values into the rich text field

Tags: apex, trigger

I am working on a trigger which will populate the date on rich text field on Lead object from Related_Tow__c object.

can anyone help me out in checking rich text field whether it contains data or not, if it contains then don't add else add.

for example, I have 70;100 on rich text field then next time I dont want to add 70 again to the rich text field, my trigger is below.

```
public class RelatedTowtoContact {
public static void relatedtows(List<Related_TOW__c> allrelatedtows){
    //List<Related_TOW__c> allrelatedtows = [select Id, Name, Lead__c, Contact__c,Tow_Id__c, TOW__c from Related_TOW__c where Id IN: alltows];
    set<Id> contactid = new set<Id>();
    set<Id> leadId = new set<Id>();
    set<Id> TowId = new set<Id>();
    for(Related_TOW__c tow: allrelatedtows){
        if(tow.Lead__c != NULL){
            leadId.add(tow.Lead__c);
        }
        if(tow.TOW__c!= null){
            TowId.add(tow.TOW__c);
        }
        if(tow.Contact__c != null){
            contactid.add(tow.Contact__c);
        }
    }
    system.debug('LeadId is :' + leadid);
    if(!leadId.isEmpty()){
    Map<Id,Lead> leadMap = new Map<Id,Lead>([select Id, Related_TOW_IDs__c from Lead where Id IN : leadId]);
    Map<Id, TOW__c> towmap = new Map<Id,TOW__c>([select Id, TOW_ID__c from TOW__c where Id IN: TowId]);
    system.debug('leadMap is :' + leadMap);
    for(Related_TOW__c t : allrelatedtows){
        if(leadmap.ContainsKey(t.Lead__c)){
        if(leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c == null){
            leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c = towMap.get(t.TOW__c).TOW_ID__c;
            system.debug('related tow is : ' + leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c);
        }
        else{
            leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c = leadMap.get(t.Lead__c).Related_TOW_IDs__c + ';' + towMap.get(t.TOW__c).TOW_ID__c;
        }
        }
    }
        ProcessorControl.inFutureContext = true;
    update leadMap.values();
        }
```

Comment: What is the specific problem or error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're doing this the hard way, or, at the very least, a harder way than is required.

At a high level, I'd recommend changing your end goal just a bit. Trying to keep data on a field X and figuring out what to add to it is harder than simply re-computing what the data on the field should now be.

Whenever you start thinking about removing (well, more like *coalescing*) duplicate data, you should immediately start thinking about using `Set` and/or `Map`.

Since you're working on a list of `Related_TOW__c`, the child object in the relationship, you'll need to do the work to group the `Related_TOW__c` records by their respective `Lead`. A `Map<Id, Set<String>>` is what I think you'll need here.

The map key is the `Lead` Id, and the `Set<String>` ensures that you'll end up with the unique values of `Tow_ID__c`.

You'll have to modify this to suit your needs, but here's some example code to get you going...

```java
// What you're doing here is essentially a rollup
// This example uses Opportunity (as the child object) and Account (as the
//   parent object)
public void rollUpChildData(List<Opportunity> oppsList){
    // This example assumes that oppsList contains ALL of the Opportunities
    //   related to the Accounts we'll encounter

    Map<Id, Set<String>> accountIdToOppCodeMap = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();

    for(Opportunity opp :oppsList){
        // This is my preferred method for initializing maps
        // Instead of using an if _and_ else block, we just check to see
        //   if we need to initialize the map value for the given key.
        // For all code in the loop after this IF, we're guaranteed to have
        //   a value for the given key.
        if(!accountIdToOppIdMap.containsKey(opp.AccountId)){
            accountIdToOppIdMap.put(opp.AccountId, new Set<String>());
        }

        // Just using Code__c as a placeholder
        // Think of it as a field whose value can appear in other records
        // This code statement works because collections (like a Set) are stored
        //   in Maps as a reference.
        // This approach wouldn't work if the map's value type is a primative (like
        //  Integer or String)
        accountIdToOppIdMap.get(opp.AccountId).add(opp.Code__c);
    }

    // Now that we're done aggregating the data, it's time to prepare our update
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

    // If you have the Id of an SObject, you don't need to run a query to be able to update
    //   those records.
    // Providing the Id as a key-value pair in the SObject constructor is all we need
    for(Id acctId :accountIdToOppCodeMap.keySet()){
        // Generally speaking, I like to avoid using if/else to check for bad/unwanted/null
        //   values in a set because we can simply call the .remove() method that the Set
        //   class provides
        Set<String> oppCodes = accountIdToOppCodeMap.get(acctId);
        oppCodes.remove(null);

        // We can easily turn a List<String> into a string using String.join(), but we
        //   have a Set instead of a List.
        // Luckily, List has a constructor that can take a Set.
        List<String> oppCodeList = new List<String>(oppCodes);

        String combinedOppCodes = String.join(oppCodeList, ';');

        // I'm just adding an account to the list directly instead of making a separate
        //   variable for the account.
        // The important thing here is that we're using the SObject constructor and passing
        // <fieldName> = <value> pairs (separated by commas, like you do with any other method
        //   call)
        accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(
            Id = acctId,
            Related_Opp_Codes__c = combinedOppCodes
        ));
    }

    update accountsToUpdate;
}
```

Without all of my comments, that amounts to 30 lines of code (including blank lines).

If the `List<Related_TOW__c>` that you're passing in doesn't satisfy the condition where it contains *all* of the records that are related to the `Lead`s you'll encounter, you can still use this approach. In that case, you'll just need to gather all of the `Lead` Ids and perform a query for the related `Related_TOW__c` records. You'd then iterate over the results of that query instead of the `List<Related_TOW__c>` that you pass in to the method.